# Prerequirements to start with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to JDBC. I would like to know what I should install in my machine before starting off with JDBC. It would be most appreciated if you can also give me links to find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read the tutorial first.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Besides a working database, all you need is the JDK and the database-specific JDBC driver. You'll need to find and download the driver for the database you're going to use.

If you want to learn JDBC and don't care about a specific database, I can recommend [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), which is a lightweight DB that you can run on your machine or even from your process.

And I agree with qrtt1's advice - the best place to start is Sun/Oracle's JDBC tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Read "Before you Begin" in this [JDBC Tutorial](http://www.raima.com/jdbc-tutorial/); for use with any JDBC Database, including Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Pretty much all you need is:

- JDK 1.6 or greater installed and ready to go.
- A text editor.
- A JDBC Database Driver contained in products such as MySQL or PostgreSQL